# Question regarding adding bar labels to grouped bar chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot grouped bar charts.  I would like to add the labelsz and labelsJ at top of each bar.  Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
labels = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3']
betaz = [0.5, 0.6, 0.4]
labelsz = ['***','***','**']

betaJ = [-0.8, -0.9, -0.2]
labelsJ = ['***','***','***']

x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.35 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, betaz, width, label=r'$\beta_z$', color='navy')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, betaJ, width, label=r'$\beta_{JOE}$', color='gray')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I tried using ax.bar_label(labelsz) and ax.bar_label(labelsJ) but I keep getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'patches'.  I am pretty new to matplotlib and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, betaz, width, label=r'$\beta_z$', color='navy')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, betaJ, width, label=r'$\beta_{JOE}$', color='gray')
ax.bar_label(rects1, labelsz,label_type='edge')
ax.bar_label(rects2, labelsJ,label_type='edge')
```

this is how to write ax.bar_label